# Survival analysis with discrete (non-binary) outcome variable

Tags: survival

I would like to know whether there are any survival analysis methods to model a *discrete or continuous* variable, rather than a binary alive/dead variable. For example, asking not "how many patients will die by time X" but "how many near-fatal events they have by time X?"

My data consist of times at which various participants (in 2 conditions) completed sequential tasks (t1, t2, etc.). Some participants dropped out early, so I don't have data for later tasks. Using survival analysis, I could predict when participants would complete a task for which I have incomplete data, by treating completion as "death" and marking the time at which a participant dropped out as "alive", with later data "censored."

However, I would prefer to be able to answer the question, after 100 minutes, how many tasks would participants have, on average, completed in each group, assuming none dropped out. Here, I would like to model the continuous "tasks completed" variable over time, and account for missing data. Are there any methods well suited to this?

Comment: Although your question looks clear, it is strange to refer to a *count*--which is manifestly discrete--as a "continuous" variable.  That strongly suggests the values of these counts are typically so large that you make only a small error by supposing they are values of continuous variables.

Comment: You're right, discrete would have been more accurate. I support my phrasing was based on the assumption that any method appropriate for a continuous variable would be appropriate for a discrete one as well.

Comment: Asa far as I know, yes. You may search "multiple failure time data".